# Is it possible to use a separate thread pool for opening connections in Netty?

Tags: netty

When using Netty for a client application and sharing your I/O thread pool between connections, it is possible for connects/reconnects to exhaust the I/O thread pool if the number of connections exceed the size of the thread pool. This can potentially block existing connections from reading until the connect timeout arrives.

Does the Netty API expose a way to specify a separate thread pool that is only used for opening connections? Or is there a better way to address this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way to use a separate thread pool here. That said there is no "blocking" even in the case of connection timeouts as everything is handled in an async fashion

Comment: Thanks. Let me give a scenario just to make sure I understand. If I have a misbehaving server that will cause all connects to hit the connect timeout and all my I/O worker threads are tied up waiting for those connect operations to complete. Any inbound messages from other servers won't hit my pipeline until one of the threads becomes available. So you're correct, I am not blocking. But there are messages available that I haven't received yet and won't receive until a thread becomes available. Is that correct or am I misunderstanding how connections are established with the I/O thread pool?

Comment: the connect timeout will not block any other processing. So you should be good